# RavenDB (4.0-beta): How to full-text-search dynamic attributes

Tags: full-text-search, ravendb

I want to query an entity that contains dynamic properties with RavenDb 4.0.0-beta-40018 but am not sure on how to do it.

```
class Foo {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public dynamic Attributes { get; set; }
}

{
    "Attributes": {
        "IsFeatured": true
    },
    "CreatedAt": "2017-08-30T15:53:21.1881668Z",
    "Name": "Featured Foo"    
}
```

This is the query I tried to use.

```
const string propertyName = "IsFeatured";

var results = session.Query<Foo>()
        .Where(x => x.Attributes != null)
        .Where(x => x.Attributes[propertyName] != null)
        .Where(x => x.Attributes[propertyName] == true);
```

Sadly, I can't even compile this code as I am getting a compile error (`Error: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation`).
I don't think this is a good approach to search (with ravendb) in dynamic attributes. Are there better approaches?

Comment: Actually a good question. I believe up until RavenDB 3.5 you could use `var results = DocumentSession.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Foo>() 
    .Where("Attributes.IsFeatured: true")
    .ToList();`, but since LuceneQuery is deprecated in favor of RQL I have no idea how this is done now.

Comment: FYI: Raven Query Language (RQL) isn't in Raven 3.5. It will be in Raven 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
DocumentSession.Advanced.DocumentSession<Foo>()
  .WhereEquals("Attributes.IsFeatured", true)
  .ToList()
```

Comment: Ill accept this, but I couldn't find a reference to `DocumentSession.Advanced.DocumentSession`. You helped me getting on my way though. After a bit of searching I found this `await session.Advanced.AsyncDocumentQuery<Foo>().WhereEquals("Attributes.IsFeatured", true)` which is working for me.